# What is the difference between physical and programmatically click in browser

Tags: javascript, event-loop

When I researched the event loop, I came across this problem which I found confusing.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #outer {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
         }

         #inner {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
         }
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="outer">
         <div id="inner"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script>
      const inner = document.getElementById("inner");
      const outer = document.getElementById("outer");

      new MutationObserver(() => console.log("mutate")).observe(outer, { attributes: true });

      function onClick(e) {
          var id = e.currentTarget.id;
          console.log(`${id} click`);
          setTimeout(() => console.log(`${id} timeout`), 0);
          Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(`${id} promise`));
          outer.setAttribute("data-mutation", Math.random());
      }

      inner.addEventListener("click", onClick);
      outer.addEventListener("click", onClick);
   </script>
</html>
```

When I click the inner block, the result print as follows:

```
inner click
inner promise 
mutate 
outer click 
outer promise 
mutate 
inner timeout 
outer timeout
```

Then I add some code

```
inner.click();
console.log("end");
```

at the bottom of the script and programmatically trigger the event.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #outer {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
         }

         #inner {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: yellow;
         }
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="outer">
         <div id="inner"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script>
      const inner = document.getElementById("inner");
      const outer = document.getElementById("outer");

      new MutationObserver(() => console.log("mutate")).observe(outer, { attributes: true });

      function onClick(e) {
          var id = e.currentTarget.id;
          console.log(`${id} click`);
          setTimeout(() => console.log(`${id} timeout`), 0);
          Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(`${id} promise`));
          outer.setAttribute("data-mutation", Math.random());
      }

      inner.addEventListener("click", onClick);
      outer.addEventListener("click", onClick);
      inner.click();
      console.log("end");
   </script>
</html>
```

I got a different result, as follows:

```
inner click 
outer click 
end 
inner promise 
mutate 
outer promise 
inner timeout 
outer timeout
```

1. When I physically click, JavaScript runtime will push click-callback to task queue, and in the meantime, the execution call stack is empty.
2. When I programmatically click, JavaScript runtime does the same thing, but
   `inner.click()` is in the execution call stack.

BTW: [the explaination in MDN about programmatically click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

So what is the difference between physically and programmatically clicking in the browser? It seems that `inner.click()` is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs in a single thread mode which means talking about  sync vs async is a bit misleading especially if you come from other languages like C or Java.
All the code you run always runs to completion and in some sense everything is sync because you only have one thread to run js code (ignoring web workers which more like a separate process).
For this reason all the I/O handling is usually done through callbacks to prevent blocking the single thread (except rare deprecated exceptions like `alert()` functions or sync `XHR`). For more in depth explanation [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).
 I hope it clears some of the confusion.